# Trying to Configure Serilog Email sink with appsettings.json to work with Gmail

Tags: email, serilog

In in a POC I got the Smtp client to send emails through Gmail, so I know my information regarding connecting to Gmail's SMTP server is correct.  I am now trying to configure Serilog through appsettings.json to send my log entries through Gmail.  I need to be able to configure it different for different environments.  I currently have it set to Verbose so that I get anything...it won't be that way later.  I am not getting anything but my file log entry.  I had this working with a local network SMTP server that took defaults and no network credentials.  Now I need to set the port, ssl, and network credentials to be able to send through Gmail.

Here is my WriteTo section...

```
 "WriteTo": [      
      {
        "Name": "RollingFile",
        "Args": {
          "pathFormat": "C:/log/log-{Date}.json",
          "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog",
          "fileSizeLimitBytes": 2147483648,
          "retainedFileCountLimit": 180,
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Verbose"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Email",
        "Args": {
          "connectionInfo": {
            "FromEmail": "{email address}",
            "ToEmail": "{email address}",
            "MailServer": "smtp.gmail.com",
            "EmailSubject": "Fatal Error",
            "NetworkCredentials": {
              "userName": "{gmailuser}@gmail.com",
              "password": "{gmailPassword}"
            },
            "Port": 587,
            "EnableSsl" : true
          },          
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Verbose"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's an old one question but may be it will be helpfull for the future. Here's solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50387469/net-core-and-serilog-email-sink-json-config

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your port number to 465 and it should work for you.  Here's a some info on gmail smtp settings: https://www.lifewire.com/what-are-the-gmail-smtp-settings-1170854

I'm using Core 2.0 and couldn't get the serilog email sink to work with the appsettings.json file, but I do have it working by setting the configs in the program.cs file like so:

```cs
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
.WriteTo.RollingFile(
    pathFormat: "..\\..\\log\\AppLog.Web-{Date}.txt",
    outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] [{SourceContext}] [{EventId}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
)
.WriteTo.Email(new EmailConnectionInfo
    {
        FromEmail = appConfigs.Logger.EmailSettings.FromAddress,
        ToEmail = appConfigs.Logger.EmailSettings.ToAddress,
        MailServer = "smtp.gmail.com",
        NetworkCredentials = new NetworkCredential {
            UserName = appConfigs.Logger.EmailSettings.Username,
            Password = appConfigs.Logger.EmailSettings.Password
        },
        EnableSsl = true,
        Port = 465,
        EmailSubject = appConfigs.Logger.EmailSettings.EmailSubject
    },
    outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
    batchPostingLimit: 10
    , restrictedToMinimumLevel: Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Error
)
.CreateLogger();
```

Comment: In my case the reason is from .json Serilog doesn't seem to care about Port number, and forces 25.

Comment: Serilog.Synk.Email will not work with appsettings.json. I gave another answer with the workaround for appsettings.json

Comment: What is `appConfigs.Logger` ? and `batchPostingLimit` ?

Answer (score 5):

appsettings won´t work for Serilog.Synk.Email if you need NetworkCredentials. It will raise this exception: `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot create instance of type 'System.Net.ICredentialsByHost' because it is either abstract or an interface.'`. Use @rcf113 answer to make thing work.

To make things work with your **gmail account,** you have to:

1. EnableSsl: true
2. Port: 465
3. Create [app password](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en)

To make **appsettings** work, you'll have to come up with a custom implementation. This solution was given from @adriangutowski [github answer](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-email/issues/90#issuecomment-746921367)

Create a custom static extension class to instance a `NetworkCredential` for `ICredentialsByHost` property

```cs
    namespace MyWebApi.Extensions
    {
    
        public static class SerilogCustomEmailExtension
        {
            const string DefaultOutputTemplate = "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}";
    
            public static LoggerConfiguration CustomEmail(
                this LoggerSinkConfiguration loggerConfiguration,
                CustomEmailConnectionInfo connectionInfo,
                string outputTemplate = DefaultOutputTemplate,
                LogEventLevel restrictedToMinimumLevel = LevelAlias.Minimum
            )
            {
                return loggerConfiguration.Email(
                    connectionInfo,
                    outputTemplate,
                    restrictedToMinimumLevel
                );
            }
    
            public class CustomEmailConnectionInfo : EmailConnectionInfo
            {
                public CustomEmailConnectionInfo()
                {
                    NetworkCredentials = new NetworkCredential();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Then configure your appsettings `Serilog.Using` with your assembly name (not namespace) and add a new entry to `Serilog.WriteTo[]`

```json
    
      "Serilog": {
        "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Email", "MyWebApi" ],
        "MinimumLevel": "Error",
        "WriteTo": [
          {
            "Name": "CustomEmail",
            "Args": {
              "ConnectionInfo": {
                "NetworkCredentials": {
                  "UserName": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaa@gmail.com",
                  "Password": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
                },
                "FromEmail": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaa@gmail.com",
                "MailServer": "smtp.gmail.com",
                "EmailSubject": "[{Level}] Log Email",
                "Port": "465",
                "IsBodyHtml": false,
                "EnableSsl": true,
                "ToEmail": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaa@gmail.com"
              },
              "RestrictedToMinimumLevel": "Error",
              "OutputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm} [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
```

This configuration worked fine using

- Dotnet Core 6
- Serilog.Sinks.Email Version="2.4.0"