# Need to add file and list logging to my application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging, .net-core, ilogger

I'm configuring logging in my application something like this.

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
    {
        logging.ClearProviders();
        logging.AddConsole();
    });
```

This works fine for logging to the console.

But now I also need the following:

1. I need to log to a log file.
2. I need to capture the logging entries somehow so that I can put them in an email, which I will build and send when the application is done.

How could I best implement these two needs? I thought about creating a custom `ILoggerProvider` that stores the entries in a list, but then how could I access that list from my main program?

*Note: If it makes any difference, this is actually a console application running as a cron service. I'm using `CreateDefaultBuilder()` so my console application can support logging, database, dependency injection, etc.*

Comment: Can you pass the same list instance into your custom `ILoggerProvider` as well as the "main program" consuming it as constructor parameter? If you already have dependency injection, you could inject the list to any service including the custom logger provider and the consumer.

Comment: I would go with [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) logging library? You can see one example of using Serilog for logging to a log file, and to email sink [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46942106/trying-to-configure-serilog-email-sink-with-appsettings-json-to-work-with-gmail/46954678#46954678)