# Serilog how to send email to multiple recipients

Tags: serilog, serilog-aspnetcore

I am working on a background worker service and trying to send emails to **multiple recipients** with the configuration below. But unfortunately, It does not work. Is there a way to send email to multiple recipients? I searched Google but couldn't find a way through. (serilog aspnet core 6.1 and email sink 2.4)

```
{
        "Name": "CustomEmail",
        "Args": {
          "ConnectionInfo": {
            "NetworkCredentials": {
             
              "UserName": "support@support.com",
              "Password": "1234"
            },
            "FromEmail": "support@support.com",
            "MailServer": "smtp.gmail.com",
            "EmailSubject": "[{Level}] Multiple Requests",
            "Port": "465",
            "IsBodyHtml": false,
            "EnableSsl": true,
            "ToEmail": "to1@gmail.com; to2@gmail.com",
            "RestrictedToMinimumLevel": "Error",
            "OutputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm} [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
          }

        }
      }
```

Both of the usages below did not work. No errors and no emails. By the way, sending an email to **only one recipient works**.

```
"ToEmail": "to1@gmail.com; to2@gmail.com"
"ToEmail": "to1@gmail.com;to2@gmail.com"
"ToEmail": "to1@gmail.com, to2@gmail.com"
"ToEmail": "to1@gmail.com,to2@gmail.com"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post helped me solve my problem.

[Serilog Email Sink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46942106/trying-to-configure-serilog-email-sink-with-appsettings-json-to-work-with-gmail)

```
"Serilog": {
  "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Email", "PurchaseRazerCodesMultipleRequestService", "Serilog.Sinks.File", "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer" ],
  "Override": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
  },


{
  "Name": "CustomEmail",
  "Args": {
    "ConnectionInfo": {
      "NetworkCredentials": {
        "UserName": "support@support.com",
        "Password": "123456"
      },
      "FromEmail": "support@support.com",
      "MailServer": "smtp.gmail.com",
      "EmailSubject": "[{Level}] Test Requests",
      "Port": "465",
      "IsBodyHtml": false,
      "EnableSsl": true,
      "ToEmail": "test1@gmail.com, test2@gmail.com",
      "RestrictedToMinimumLevel": "Error",
      "OutputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm} [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
    }

  }
}

public static class SerilogCustomEmailExtension
{
    const string DefaultOutputTemplate = "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}";

    public static LoggerConfiguration CustomEmail(
        this LoggerSinkConfiguration loggerConfiguration,
        CustomEmailConnectionInfo connectionInfo,
        string outputTemplate = DefaultOutputTemplate,
        LogEventLevel restrictedToMinimumLevel = LogEventLevel.Error
    )
    {
        return loggerConfiguration.Email(
            connectionInfo,
            outputTemplate,
            restrictedToMinimumLevel
        );
    }

    public class CustomEmailConnectionInfo : EmailConnectionInfo
    {
        public CustomEmailConnectionInfo()
        {
            NetworkCredentials = new NetworkCredential();
        }
    }
}
```