How to set username and password for authetication Serilog.Sinks.Email 4.0?
I would like to send email when error occurs in my NET 8.0 application.
{
"Name": "Email",
"Args": {
    "From": "fromemail@xxx.yy",
    "Host": "smtp.server.com",
    "Subject": "Any subject",
    "Port": "2500",
    "To": "zzz@xxx.yyy",
    "NetworkCredentials": {
        "UserName": "username",
        "Password": "password"
    }
}

The above settings are working with my test SMTP application. Why is it not working with serilog?

This worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46942106/trying-to-configure-serilog-email-sink-with-appsettings-json-to-work-with-gmail

Thanks! Unfortunately it is not working with serilog 4.0.

I made a similar solution as this Trying to Configure Serilog Email sink with appsettings.json to work with Gmail
public static class SerilogCustomEmailExtension
{
    const string DefaultOutputTemplate = "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}";
    
    public static LoggerConfiguration CustomEmail(

            this LoggerSinkConfiguration loggerConfiguration,
            CustomEmailSinkOptions server,
            BatchingOptions batchingOptions,
            string outputTemplate = DefaultOutputTemplate,
            LogEventLevel restrictedToMinimumLevel = LevelAlias.Minimum
    )
    {
        var t = server.ToEmailSinkOptions();
        return loggerConfiguration.Email(t, batchingOptions, restrictedToMinimumLevel);
        
    }

    public class CustomEmailSinkOptions
    {
        internal const int DefaultPort = 25;

        private const string DefaultSubject = "Log Messages";

        private const string DefaultBody = "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}";

        internal const SecureSocketOptions DefaultConnectionSecurity = SecureSocketOptions.Auto;

        public EmailSinkOptions ToEmailSinkOptions()
        {
            return new EmailSinkOptions
            {
                Port = Port,
                Credentials = Credentials,
                Host = Host,
                Subject = SubjectF,
                From = From,
                To = To
            };
        }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The email address emails will be sent from.
        public string From { get; set; }

        //
        // Summary:
        //     The email address(es) emails will be sent to.
        public List<string> To { get; set; } = new List<string>();


        //
        // Summary:
        //     The SMTP email server to use.
        public string Host { get; set; }

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the port used for the SMTP connection. The default is 25.
        public int Port { get; set; } = 25;


        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the credentials used for authentication.
        public ICredentialsByHost? Credentials { get; set; }

        //
        // Summary:
        //     The Serilog.Formatting.ITextFormatter or Serilog.Sinks.Email.IBatchTextFormatter
        //     implementation to write log entries to email. Specify null to use the default
        //     body. . Consider using Serilog.Formatting.Display.MessageTemplateTextFormatter
        //     or Serilog.Expressions templates.
        public ITextFormatter SubjectF => new MessageTemplateTextFormatter(Subject);

        public string Subject { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The Serilog.Formatting.ITextFormatter implementation to format email subjects.
        //     Specify null to use the default subject. Consider using Serilog.Formatting.Display.MessageTemplateTextFormatter
        //     or Serilog.Expressions templates.
        public ITextFormatter Body { get; set; } = new MessageTemplateTextFormatter("{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}");


        //
        // Summary:
        //     Sets whether the body contents of the email is HTML. Defaults to false.
        public bool IsBodyHtml { get; set; }

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Choose the security applied to the SMTP connection. This enumeration type is
        //     supplied by MailKit; see MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions for supported values.
        //     The default is MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions.Auto.
        public SecureSocketOptions ConnectionSecurity { get; set; } = SecureSocketOptions.Auto;


        //
        // Summary:
        //     Provides a method that validates server certificates.
        public RemoteCertificateValidationCallback? ServerCertificateValidationCallback { get; set; }

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Constructs an Serilog.Sinks.Email.EmailSinkOptions with default options.
        public CustomEmailSinkOptions()
        {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential();
        }
    }
}

